# Index out of range for only last 2 values?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently getting index out of range but this only happens after the first 3 items have been displayed successfully. I looked through the code and I still don't know where im going wrong. Index out of range happens only when trying to load text in the cells.

Log when method is called from viewdidload:

> Description of indexPath:  0
>   Description of indexPath:  1
>   Description of indexPath:  2

Log when I press a button to load the rest of images:

> Description of indexPath:  0
>   Description of indexPath:  1
>   Description of indexPath:  2
>   Description of indexPath:  3

Datasource method where indexpath is out of range:

```
    //MARK: - tableview datasource methods

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    if arrayOfImgObj.count > 0 {
        cell.imageView?.image = arrayOfImgObj[indexPath.row].imageTempt
        print("Description of indexPath: ",indexPath.row)
        cell.textLabel?.text = arrayOfUIDs[indexPath.row] // index out of range
    } else {
        print("\(arrayOfImgObj.count) not over 0 yet")
    }
    return cell
}
```

Method that is called when viewDidload:

```
    //testing array
var arrayOfUIDs = User().users

func fetchAllUserFristImage() {
    Database.database().reference().child("Posts").observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in

        if (snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]) != nil {
            let user = User()

            user.id = snapshot.key

            //testing array
            self.arrayOfUIDs.append(snapshot.key)

            print("\(String(describing: user.id)) <-- SHUD BE THE USERUID")

            self.databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

            let usersPostRef2 = self.databaseRef.child("Posts").child(user.id!)

            usersPostRef2.observe(.value, with: {(postXSnapshots) in

                if let postDictionary2 = postXSnapshots.value as? NSDictionary {

                    for (p) in postDictionary2 {

                        let posts = p.value as! NSDictionary

                        //to get back to where i was delete the below for i
                        for (i) in posts {

                            let imageUrlString = i.value as! NSDictionary

                            guard let postUrl = imageUrlString.value(forKey: "image1") else {return}

                            //below is ting from below
                            if postUrl != nil {

                                self.feedArray.append(Post(fetchedImageURL: postUrl as! String))

                                let imageUrlString = "\(postUrl)"

                                let imageUrl = URL(string: imageUrlString)!
                                print("\(imageUrl) this shud be img url's of posts")

                                let imageDataL = try! Data(contentsOf: imageUrl)
                                self.imageObject.img2 = UIImage(data: imageDataL)
                                let image1ToDisplay: UIImage = self.imageObject.img2!
                                self.arrayOfImgObj.append(forTable(imageTempt: image1ToDisplay))

                            } else {print("this user had no posts, was nil")}
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        //below shud stay same
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```

**Edit:**

I have changed teh code to only use one array of objects:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    if arrayOfImgObj.count > 0 {
        cell.imageView?.image = arrayOfImgObj[indexPath.row].imageTempt
        print("Description of indexPath: ",indexPath.row)
        cell.textLabel?.text = arrayOfImgObj[indexPath.row].users[indexPath.row] // index out of range
    } else {
        print("\(arrayOfImgObj.count) not over 0 yet")
    }

    return cell
}
```

changing one line in the function to this:

```
self.arrayOfImgObj.append(forTable(imageTempt: image1ToDisplay, users: snapshot.key))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Reload the table inside the completion of your network call.

Comment: show your `numerOfRows` code - This function should return the `count` of your array.  You must be returning a count more than the number of elements in your array.

Comment: I just return arrayOfImgObj.count @Paulw11

Comment: So, what is the relationship between `arrayOfUIDs` and `arrayOfImgObj` ?  It is probably a better idea to use a single array of structs rather than two separate arrays.  When you have separate arrays you often end up with these sorts of crashes

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use `NSDictionary` in Swift if it can be avoided.

Comment: what shoudl I use instead of NSDictionary is Dictionary a option? also why is it that its not recommended?

Comment: Yes, you should use the appropriate Dictionary type, possibly `[String:Any]`.  Why do you say it is not recommenced?  The use of Swift types is definitely recommended.

Comment: @Paulw11 I changed my code to only use one array, but it failed, I get only this printed ion teh console: Description of indexPath:  0
Description of indexPath:  1

Comment: I added my change in teh question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have two arrays:

- `arrayOfUIDs` which has one entry for each user
- `arrayOfImgObj` which has 0-n entries for each user (So, it is likely that the number of objects in this array will be greater than the number of objects in `arrayOfUIDs`.

You are basing your row count on the `arrayOfImgObj`, but then using the row number to index into `arrayOfUIDs`, which results in an array bounds exception.

It may well be more elegant to have table view section per userid, but if you want to put all of the rows in a single section I would suggest you use a single array of structs as your data model.

Use something like:

```
struct UserImage {
    var userID: String
    var image: UIImage
}


var tableData = [UserImage]()
```

Then as you fetch each image, create a new struct and put it in your array:

```
func fetchAllUserFristImage() {
    Database.database().reference().child("Posts").observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in

        if snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] != nil {
            let user = snapshot.key

            self.databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

            let usersPostRef2 = self.databaseRef.child("Posts").child(user)

            usersPostRef2.observe(.value, with: {(postXSnapshots) in

                if let postDictionary2 = postXSnapshots.value as? [String:AnyObject] {

                    for (p) in postDictionary2 {

                        if let posts = p.value as? [String:AnyObject] {

                            //to get back to where i was delete the below for i
                            for (i) in posts {

                                if let imageUrlString = i.value as? [String:AnyObject], let postUrl = imageUrlString.["image1"] as? String {

                                    self.feedArray.append(Post(fetchedImageURL: postUrl))
                                    if let imageUrl = URL(string: postUrl), let imageDataL = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl), let image = UIImage(data: imageDataL) {

                                        self.tableData.append(UserImage(userID: user, image: image))
                                    } else {print("this user had no posts, was nil")}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
                //below shud stay same
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })

}
```

Now, your `cellForRow` can be:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.imageView?.image = tableData[indexPath.row].image
    cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row].userID

    return cell
}
```

Comment: dont delete your answer I will test it in about an hour

Comment: it seems to be running properly but its not displaying teh images in the table view: i tried printing sothing out in teh tableview methods but that print statement was never called

Comment: Addingchar@Paulw11